# Error while adding Xamarin plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Visual Studio 2015. I get this error while I'm trying to add a messaging plugin.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.0.1.3' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.0.1.3 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.0.1.3)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)'.            0

I have already updated Visual Studio and Xamarin, but still get this error.
What else should I do to fix this error?

Comment: is that `Xamarin.Android` project or `Xamarin.Forms` project?

Comment: I'm trying on Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 7):

This is a dependency issue. For [Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.2.0.45), the dependencies are

- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)

Note version conflict between the above and the error: `'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.0.1.3' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.0.1.3 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.0.1.3)'`

You will need to install the compatible version of the messaging plugin you’d like to use. Here is a related troubleshooting guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/.